# Cycle Multiple values through a stored procedure (MYSQL)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, stored-procedures

I'm calling a stored procedure that only accepts one value. The values come from users entering multiple values, at a max of 10. I don't know how many they will enter at a given time, just a maximum of 10.  I'm trying to put these values through a loop that has the stored procedure within.  In my PHP script, I'm doing this:

```
<?php
    include("include/database.php");
    $containers = ['TCNU3155045',
        'TRIU8054996',
        'CMAU0299010',
        'GESU6875432',
        'TGHU3944633',
        'NEUL0325B'];

    echo "<=====This is simulated input<br>" . print_r($containers);
    $shortened = array();
    foreach ($containers as $short) {
        $shortened[] = substr($short, 0, 10);
    }
    echo "<===no check# <br />" . print_r($shortened);
    $sans_check = preg_replace('/\n$/', '', preg_replace('/^\n/', '', preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $shortened)));
    echo "<===on one line#" . print_r($sans_check);
    $count   = count($sans_check);
    $filtres = array();
    foreach ($shortened as $singles) {
        $thecall   = "CALL SP_TEST1($singles)";
        $filtres[] = $thecall;
    }
    echo $filtres;
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $thecall);
    if (query) {
        echo "Successful";
    } else {
        echo "CALL failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
    }
?>
```

I'm trying to push each value through the stored procedure, then push the results into an array, so that I can return them through json in jquery.  Currently, no errors are coming up or neither is "Successful".  All I get is a blank browser screen.  I'm at a loss.  If someone could point me in the right direction or help get through the logic, it would be awesome.  Thanks!

Comment: Clean, properly formatted code will help you debug your code and find simple syntax issues.

Comment: You have a syntax error on the line before `$filtres[] = $thecall;` - you're missing the ending semi-colon

Comment: Isn't that much easier to read? ;)

Comment: thanks!  I was just wondering if my logic was okay.  Is it clear to you what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yeah it looks pretty standard to me to be honest. Did fixing that syntax issue fix your problem? I hadn't actually read your question until now, as I noticed the syntax issue before - not sure if it's resolved yet

Comment: No unfortunately, it didn't.  I didn't get a successful to print on the screen, it's just blank.

Comment: Are you using some sort of framework? I've never seen anyone include a database connection the way you have, and syntax checkers pick it up as an error - maybe your connection isn't actually working?

Comment: No.  I'll fix that.   It's definitely connected.

Comment: How are you so sure?

Comment: well, I took the query out of the stored procedure and ran it on my php script.  Pushed the values thru the query and it returned data.  Do you mind taking this to chat? Stackoverflow apparently discourages extended discussions in comments.

Comment: I actually can't right now. I suggest updating your code to fix the syntax issue I pointed out, and maybe someone else will come along to help out

Comment: I did fix it.  Still nothing.  Understandable, thanks for formatting my code and giving me a heads up on the syntax issue. Should I go to the chat and post my question there?

Comment: No. That's not the proper place, all you gotta do now is wait :) - and I mean't edit the code IN the question, to show that syntax error doesn't exist anymore.